# Fail to send a wesbite link

Tags: html, web, google-drive-api

my goal is to host my `.html` files (dynamic and static) on GoogleDrive and then, share that file to anyone. So, I imported that file into my Google Drive and made it "Anyone with the link" so that it is accessible by anyone. When I copied the link and pasted it in the URL, it failed (it only gave me the `html` script, not the website page).

So, I found a website `drv.tw` which allow you to make the "connection" with your Google Drive, and it provides you a new URL which works. The problem is when I want to send that URL to my friend on Facebook for example, it failed with this kind of error message "Impossible to send the message" .

Do you know `drv.tw` and if yes, is it "dangerous" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using drv.tw is not at all it asks permission to access your google drive which is not safe.

Here are some great websites to host your sites (free) -

[Netlify](https://netlify.com)

[Now.sh](https://now.sh)

I mainly use these two and both of them are great. They also give Free SSL certificates for your site.

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean. Thanks for the tip